# How to calculate the median time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in which I need to calculate the median of time in the format hh: mm: ss for each user

[image]

my code

```
file['date'] = pd.to_datetime(file['date'])
file['diff'] = file.groupby(['operation', 'user'])['date'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)) #calculate the time difference between operations
file = file.loc[file['diff'] <= '00:00:20']  # we leave those where the difference is not more than 20 seconds
results = file.groupby(['operation', 'user'])['diff'].median() #caclulate median
```

python throws an error - No numeric types to aggregate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) for convert tiemdeltas to seconds, replace `NaN` by `0`, compare by `20`:

```
file['date'] = pd.to_datetime(file['date'])

#calculate the time difference between operations
file['diff']=file.groupby(['operation','user'])['date'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)

file= file.loc[file['diff'] <= 20] #remove difference less than 20 seconds

results = file.groupby(['operation', 'user'])['diff'].median()


result_of_operation = results.groupby('operation')['diff'].median()
```

If need timedeltas add [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
result_of_operation = pd.to_timedelta(result_of_operation, unit='s')
```

Last if need DataFrame:

result_of_operation = result_of_operation.reset_index()

Comment: I would also like to calculate the median for operations. But the code,

result_of_operation = results.groupby('operation')['diff'].median()
which in the screenshot is in line 31, gives an error - No numeric types to aggregate again

Comment: @RinatDevyatyarov - Added to answer. basically need numeric seconds if need working with data, to timedeltas use for last step, after working with all methods.